# JButton's ActionListener is responding yet code is apparently not being executed, but when I call method directly, it is. Very strange behavior?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

When I add the `ActionListener` and put code in the `actionPerformed`, which calls a method, the method is called just fine, yet the code within it, which is supposed to dynamically add various Swing components, doesn't seem to be responding.  When I add the line just outside the `ActionListener`, however, the same code is ran and the components are being added just fine.  It is very strange and I'm not sure what the problem is.

When I add something like a `System.out.println` statement within the action performed method to add an appliance, it is obviously being called, but nothing is being added to the `JPanel`.  When I put that `System.out.println` within the `addAppliance()` method, it is being called just fine as well.  Like I said, a very strange problem.  Here is my entire program so far:

```
package Main;    
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ElectricPanel extends JPanel
{
  private static final int WIDTH = 360;
  private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
  private ArrayList<JTextField> description;
  private ArrayList<JTextField> volts;
  private ArrayList<JTextField> current;
  private ArrayList<JTextField> power;
  private JButton addButton;
  private JButton subtractButton;
  private JLabel[] labels;
  private int numOfAppliances;
  public ElectricPanel()
  {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));  
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    setLayout(null);
    description = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    volts = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    current = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    power = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    labels = new JLabel[]{new JLabel("Description"),
        new JLabel("Volts"),
        new JLabel("Current"),
        new JLabel("Power")};
    Dimension size = labels[0].getPreferredSize();
    labels[0].setBounds(10, 10, size.width, size.height);
    size = labels[1].getPreferredSize();
    labels[1].setBounds(125, 10, size.width, size.height);
    size = labels[2].getPreferredSize();
    labels[2].setBounds(185, 10, size.width, size.height);
    size = labels[3].getPreferredSize();
    labels[3].setBounds(245, 10, size.width, size.height);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      add(labels[i]);
    }
    numOfAppliances = 0;
    addAppliance();
    setupAddAndSubtractButtons();
  }
  private void setupAddAndSubtractButtons()
  {
    Insets insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    addButton = new JButton("+");
    subtractButton = new JButton("-");
    addButton.setBounds(305, 30, 24, 18);
    subtractButton.setBounds(305, 50, 24, 18);
    subtractButton.setVisible(false);
    addButton.setMargin(insets);
    subtractButton.setMargin(insets);
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        addAppliance();
      }
    });
    subtractButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
      {
        subtractAppliance();
      }
    });
    add(addButton);
    add(subtractButton);
    addAppliance();
  }
  private void tryToAdd()
  {
    addAppliance();
  }
  private void addAppliance()
  {
    description.add(new JTextField(10));
    volts.add(new JTextField(5));
    current.add(new JTextField(5));
    power.add(new JTextField(5));

    Dimension size = description.get(numOfAppliances).getPreferredSize();
    description.get(numOfAppliances).setBounds(10, 30 + 20 * numOfAppliances, size.width, size.height);
    size = volts.get(numOfAppliances).getPreferredSize();
    volts.get(numOfAppliances).setBounds(125, 30 + 20 * numOfAppliances, size.width, size.height);
    size = current.get(numOfAppliances).getPreferredSize();
    current.get(numOfAppliances).setBounds(185, 30 + 20 * numOfAppliances, size.width, size.height);
    size = power.get(numOfAppliances).getPreferredSize();
    power.get(numOfAppliances).setBounds(245, 30 + 20 * numOfAppliances, size.width, size.height);

    add(description.get(numOfAppliances));
    add(volts.get(numOfAppliances));
    add(current.get(numOfAppliances));
    add(power.get(numOfAppliances));

    numOfAppliances++;
  }
  private void subtractAppliance()
  {
    int index = numOfAppliances - 1;
    description.remove(index);
    volts.remove(index);
    current.remove(index);
    power.remove(index);
  }
}
```

Any and all help and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you resize the window (if it is resizable of course) after you click the buttons, you will notice that the button clicks are taking effect. What is happening is that you are adding components, but not repainting the panel. Just add a `repaint()` call inside the `actionPerformed()` methods and your changes will show up.

The reason the methods were working outside the action listeners is that the method calls were taking place prior to the panel being first painted. Whereas, when the method calls were inside the action listeners, they were being executed once you click on the button, after the panel was painted.

Aside from that though, you definitely shouldn't be using a null layout, that will make your GUI limited to the computer you are working on. Also, read up on [Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I decided against a layout because I felt absolute positioning was the best, plus the easiest in this case, to implement.  It is hectic dealing with some of those layout managers.  I figured FlowLayout would go well with this but I couldn't get it to look good as I could with no layout manager.

Comment: I agree Swing layout managers are terrible, but f you want your GUI to run one more than one device, you will need a layout manager. I recommend using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), it uses simple String constraints. Also, accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: @PeterGriffin It might seem like absolute positioning is a good idea, until you run it on a different machine. You don't control the properties of the pipeline which will change the size of the graphical elements and turn your, pretty, pixel perfect layout into spaghetti. The core Swing API is designed around the use of layout managers, so not only do you lose the flexibility of variable graphics configurations, you also lose much of the underlying update mechanisms as well

Comment: @dramzy How do you accept the answer?  If you mean vote up, it says I don't have enough reputation.